# What does Compute Snasphot for version : 3001 means in databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming, delta-lake

I have a spark streaming query running in databricks. While loading data from a kafka topic to delta lake, the cell output while running displays "Compute snapshot for version : 3001". I saw this message many times before but it was the first time I'm seeing an abnormally huge number.

What exactly does this message mean ? How should one intrepret what's happening under the hood?
Also, does having a high number have any impact on performance of the task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question I've inferred that you are saving the data into a `Delta Lake` format, which by design have a concept of *Time Travel*, which in principle allows you to track the changes in the underlying data by saving so-called *snapshots* of the table:

- more about Snaphots - https://books.japila.pl/delta-lake-internals/Snapshot/
- more about Time Travel in Delta Lake - https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#query-an-older-snapshot-of-a-table-time-travel

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you also please tell me in what cases, there will be a huge number of snapshots created ?

Comment: The snapshot is created whenever there is a change in the Delta Table, so for streaming query, it should be every time a new batch of data is being written.